# Failure in writing large spark dataframes to csv from databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, export-to-csv, databricks

I'm processing large spark dataframe in databricks and when I'm trying to write the final dataframe into csv format it gives me the following error:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

```
#Creating a data frame with entire date seuence for each user
df=pd.DataFrame({'transaction_date':dt_range2,'msno':msno1})

from pyspark.sql.types import *

mySchema1 = StructType([StructField("transaction_date", DateType(), True),
                         StructField("msno", StringType(), True)
                         ])

#user wise date sequence conversion to pyspark data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema=mySchema1)

#writing to a csv
df.write.csv("dbfs:/mnt/entracermount1/kkbox/Data_test.csv")
```

```
#full traceback
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3754966373119602> in <module>
----> 1 df.write.csv("dbfs:/mnt/entracermount1/kkbox/Data_test.csv")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue)
    930                        charToEscapeQuoteEscaping=charToEscapeQuoteEscaping,
    931                        encoding=encoding, emptyValue=emptyValue)
--> 932         self._jwrite.csv(path)
    933 
    934     @since(1.5)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1459.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:698)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 64:0 was 614833921 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (268435456 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2360)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2348)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2347)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2347)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1101)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2579)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2527)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2515)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    ... 34 more
```

Even I have tried to save as parquet file and it is giving the same error. If you could suggest any solution for this it will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please show full traceback as text, not an image

Comment: Added the full traceback

Comment: `Serialized task 64:0 was 614833921 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (268435456 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values`

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Could you try df.cache().count() and then save the file. And also which java version are you using?

Comment: The solution is given to you in the error message. Update your SparkContext options to increase that variable. Otherwise, it's not clear where your data comes from, but do you need to load it in Pandas first, or can you load it into Spark dataframes from the beginning?

Comment: I'm doing kind of simulation to take the date sequence in pandas. That is why I need to start with pandas.

Comment: Java version 1.8.0_222 (Private Build)

Comment: df.cache().count() gives me the error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 65:0 was 614833681 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (268435456 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.

Comment: How should I update sparkcontext to increase spark.rpc.message.maxSize?

Comment: Managed to change spark configurations. https://kb.databricks.com/execution/spark-serialized-task-is-too-large.html

Answer (score 0):

Spark configurations needs to be changed when initializing the cluster. Please refer https://kb.databricks.com/execution/spark-serialized-task-is-too-large.html for details.

Problem sorted.
Thanks for the help everyone.